# Slackware current and Radeon HD 6450: on OpenGL

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

I've upgraded to Slackware current  (from 14.1) and everything works perfectly fine, except for OpenGL. Fglrx 15.302 doesn't compile against the running kernel (4.4.5) so I decided to stick with the free driver. However it doesn't work at all though everything looks fine:

```
 lsmod | egrep 'amdgpu|radeon'
amdgpu                574775  0
radeon               1440055  2
hwmon                   3287  3 k10temp,amdgpu,radeon
ttm                    71787  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_kms_helper        108360  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm                   277256  6 ttm,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon
i2c_algo_bit            5190  2 amdgpu,radeon
i2c_core               41745  7 drm,i2c_dev,i2c_piix4,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,amdgpu,radeon
```

Xorg.0.log mentions loading GLX extensions:

```
[  1427.634] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1427.635] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1427.647] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1427.647] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  1427.647] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
<snip the list of cards>
 [ 75978.088] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es{,2}_profile
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[ 76004.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[ 76004.516] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized r600
[ 76004.516] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
```

However any GL application crashes with this error:

```
 glxgears
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  23
glxinfo
name of display: :0
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

Any idea? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem came from an ancient remain of the NVIDIA installer:

```
/usr/lib/libXvMCNVIDIA.so.96.43.11
```

Removing all orphan NVIDIA files solved the problem!